# How do I save a file to my Phone's Internal Storage or SD Card?

Tags: c#, android, .net, windows

Due to several bugs in some frameworks, I have to resort to manually copying and pasting an APK file from my local machine to my Phone when connected to the machine via USB.

This is **extremely** tedious and it's getting on my nerves. So I thought it would be good to just create a console app, that watches the file system for certain changes to the file and when necessary, copy the file from the machine to a directory on the phone.

I have full file access to the phone using File Explorer in Windows. It's an Android phone (HTC One M8). And when you browse to the root directory in File Explorer, the "file path" in the address bar location of File Explorer says:

> This PC\HTC One_M8\Internal storage

or for another location:

> This PC\HTC One_M8\SD card

But when I do:

```
File.Copy(source, "This PC\HTC One_M8\Internal storage\Notes.apk", true);
```

I get the following exception:

> Could not find a part of the path 'This PC\HTC One_M8\Internal
>   storage\Notes.apk'.    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32
>   errorCode, String maybeFullPath)    at
>   System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String
>   destFileName, Boolean overwrite, Boolean checkHost)    at
>   System.IO.File.Copy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName,
>   Boolean overwrite)    at Quick_Build_Transfer.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) in C:\Users\Jase\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\My
>   Samples\Quick Build Transfer\Quick Build Transfer\Program.cs:line 33
>
> mscorlib Void WinIOError(Int32, System.String)

So my question is, how do I copy a file to the phone's internal storage, or to its SD Card?

Comment: why not simply: adb install routeofapk/apk.apk ?

Comment: @cgomezmendez OMG. I totally forgot about adb. THANKS! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
 adb install routeofapk/apk.apk
```

And it will work fine. Why don't use that?

Comment: This is perfect, thank you. I will accept the answer in 53 seconds. The timer won't let me do it yet.